# Postgresql becomes unresponsible when new index value is added

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

In my app I have a concept of "seasons" which change discretely over time. All the entities are related to some season. All entities have season based indices as well as some indices on other fields. When season change occurs, postgresql decides to use filtered scan plan based on season index rather than more specific field indices. At the beginning of the season the planning cost of such decision is very little, so it's ok, but the problem is - season change brings MANY users to come at the very beginning of the season, so postgresql scan based query plan becomes bad very fast - it simply scans all the entities in the new season, and filters target items. After first auto analyze postgres decides to use a good plan, BUT auto analyze runs VERY SLOWLY due to contention and I suppose it's like a snowball - the more requests are done, the more contention is due to a bad plan and thus auto analyze works slowly and slowly. The biggest time for auto analyze to work was about an hour last week, and it becomes a real problem. I know postgresql architects decided to disable the possibility to choose the index used in query, but what is the best way to overcome my problem then?

Just to clarify, here is a DDL, one of the "slow" queries and explain results before and after auto analyze.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE race_results (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('race_results_id_seq'::regclass),
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  opponent_id INTEGER,
  season_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type RACE_TYPE NOT NULL DEFAULT 'battle'::race_type,
  elo_delta INTEGER NOT NULL,
  opponent_elo_delta INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);
CREATE INDEX race_results_type_user_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (season_id, type, user_id);
CREATE INDEX race_results_type_opponent_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (season_id, type, opponent_id);
CREATE INDEX race_results_opponent_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (opponent_id);
CREATE INDEX race_results_user_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (user_id);
```

Query

```
SELECT 1000 + COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 6446 THEN elo_delta ELSE opponent_elo_delta END), 0)
        FROM race_results
        WHERE type = 'battle' :: race_type AND (user_id = 6446 OR opponent_id = 6446) AND
              season_id = current_season_id()
```

Results of explain before auto analyze (as you see more than a thousand items is already removed by filter and soon it becomes hundreds of thousands for each request)
[image]

Results of explain analyze after auto analyze (now postgres decides to use the right index and no filtering needed anymore, but the problem is - auto analyze takes too long partly due to contention of ineffective index selection in previous picture)
[image]

ps: Now I'm solving the problem just turning off the application server after 10 seconds after season changes so that postgres gets new data and starts autoanalyze, and then turn it on, when autoanalyze finishes, but such solution involves downtime, which is not desirable and overall it looks weird

Comment: Adding the DDL and the query to your question would help.

Comment: @wildplasser added more information

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan as [**formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text please. The screenshots are hard to read.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, it's impossible now, because I obtained them as pictures. You can click on a picture to make it bigger.

Comment: I don't understand why the first screen shot shows an "ineffective index selection". The query takes less then a millisecond using the index `race_results_type_user_id_index` - what is wrong with that? The execution plan in the second picture seems to be less efficient actually.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's millisecond when it should filter 1000 items, but when it comes to 100 000 items, it becomes much slower (I don't have that picture now) and remember that this query is invoked by all users. Average query time before autoanalyze finish is about 20 seconds. After autoanalyze finish it drops down to 0.2 ms

Comment: If you want an answer why a query is slow, show us the execution plan (generated using `explain (analyze)` - not just `explain`) for the **slow** query, not for the fast query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the first picture shows SLOW plan, it means that when it comes to filtering 100 000 items, the plan is the same, but the time grows to seconds. I've done that screenshot on a prod environment some time ago just for the inner usage and I remake it now, because new season will start some time later

Comment: `season_id = current_season_id()` The problem is that the planner cannot guess the function value and thus cannot use statistics for `season_id` (which probably is a low-cardinality column anyway) I suggest you remove the function and use a prepared query instead. And maybe add a composite index involving `season_id` (On second reading, I see you already have one)

Comment: Less then a millisecond is not slow - at least not to me. You have to show us the real "slow" plan.

Comment: @joop as I understand it can, because after first autoanalyze everything starts to work the right way

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ...huh :P as I told you it is the same, just with different number in "rows removed by filter".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you asked example with more than milliseconds - here is it, I updated first image - as you can see - there is a 2 second already, I can't grow it more, but trust me without my workarounds it will grow up to 25 seconds easily. Also it says, there is ~17000 items which need to be analyzed and this number grows and grows very fast (SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_all_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'). Autoanalyze process is started as could be seen in pg_stat_activity(SELECT * from pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE state<>'idle'). And autoanalyze could take an hour

Comment: BTW: what is *auto analyze* ?

Comment: @wildplasser It's a process, when postgres automatically (based on some predefined criteria) executes analyze on target table to update statistics for query planner. It could be confused with auto vacuum procedure, which allows postgres to reclaim memory, but it's not the same.

Comment: If you query pg_stat_activity, then I call autoanalyze processes with: 'autovacuum: ANALYZE ...' and I call autovacuum processes with: 'autovacuum: VACUUM ... '. Sometimes postgres invokes them both also: 'autovacuum: VACUUM ANALYZE ... '

Comment: what properties does current_season_id() have?

Comment: @Jasen it simply selects last row from season table like this
SELECT id FROM seasons ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: `language sql` ? Volativity is what: `stable`?

Comment: @Jasen Yes, language sql, and  volatility is not set, so it seems some default is used.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. It's not perfect and I will not mark it as the best one, however it works and could help someone.

Instead of indices on season, type and user/opponent id, I now have indices

```
CREATE INDEX race_results_type_user_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (user_id,season_id, type);
CREATE INDEX race_results_type_opponent_id_index ON race_results USING BTREE (opponent_id,season_id, type);
```

One problem which appeared - I needed and index on season anyway in other queries, but when I add index

```
CREATE INDEX race_results_season_index ON race_results USING BTREE (season_id);
```

the planner tries to use it again instead of those right indices and the whole situation is repeated. What I've done is simply added one more field: 'season_id_clone', which contains the same data as 'season_id', and I made an index against it. Now when I need to filter something based on season (not including queries from the first post), I'm using season_id_clone in query. I know it's weird, but I haven't found anything better.